# Is there any function in twisted python similar to 'select' in socket programming?

Tags: python, twisted

I am doing a muticlient chat server program in twisted python. Is there any function in twisted python similar to 'select' in in socket programming? Can anybody give me the answer please?.. If yes, please tell me the implementation, please.

Comment: What, why? Twisted uses select at a low level so that you don't have to ...

Answer (score 1):

No, there isn't.

Twisted calls `select` (or something like it) for you.

You don't ever need to call a function like `select`; just let the reactor run, and do its work for you.

Comment: But, how can I get the message in clients from server (sent by other client)?

Comment: In my program, each client gives output when it sends message from the same client. But at that time, it gives all the messages send from other clients. But, I have to get message in all clients when one of the clients sends the message. How can I get it?? please give me the answer.. Can anybody give me the implementation, please..

Comment: This doesn't seem to have anything to do with the question you've asked above.  Perhaps ask a new question?